# How to update or insert data from the parent table to the child table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Alright so I am trying to wrap my head around how to approach this but we have two tables where the Book table is the parent table to the Author table and the Author table uses two foreign keys from the book table and then has three columns for the Authors first, middle, and last name; First when I enter in the book information how do I update the author table with the same isbn and copy number? while inserting values into the AF, AM, AL columns?

```
VALUES ("1234567980605", 2, "Chaos Theory", "Mathematics", 19900910, "Steven Stugart", 450);
INSERT INTO AUTHOR (isbn, copy) SELECT ISBN FROM BOOK;
INSERT INTO AUTHOR (AF, AM, AL) VALUES ("Tony", "W", "Stark");
```

This was a query that I crafted thinking it would work but it didn't.

BOOK table

```
+---------------+------+----------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+------+
|     ISBN      | COPY |     TITLE      |    GENRE    |   PDATE    |     PUBLISHER     | SIZE |
+---------------+------+----------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+------+
| 1111111111111 |    1 | Calculus AB BC | Math        | 2000-01-02 | Pearson Education |  325 |
| 1111111111111 |    2 | Calculus AB BC | Math        | 2000-01-02 | Pearson Education |  325 |
| 1112223334445 |    2 | Test           | tst         | 2019-05-05 | testaa            |  123 |
| 1212365454789 |    1 | Math           | Mathematics | 2000-02-02 | Pearson Education |  450 |
+---------------+------+----------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+------+
```

AUTHOR table

```
+---------------+------+--------+----+---------+
|     isbn      | copy |   AF   | AM |   AL    |
+---------------+------+--------+----+---------+
| 1111111111111 |    1 | John   | M  | Smith   |
| 1111111111111 |    2 | John   | M  | Smith   |
| 1231231231231 |    1 | Peyton | M  | Manning |
+---------------+------+--------+----+---------+
```

Expected results:

```
VALUES ("1234567980605", 2, "Chaos Theory", "Mathematics", 19900910, "Steven Stugart", 450);
INSERT INTO AUTHOR (isbn, copy) SELECT ISBN FROM BOOK;
INSERT INTO AUTHOR (AF, AM, AL) VALUES ("Tony", "W", "Stark");
```

Book table

```
+---------------+------+----------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+------+
|     ISBN      | COPY |     TITLE      |    GENRE    |   PDATE    |     PUBLISHER     | SIZE |
+---------------+------+----------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+------+
| 1111111111111 |    1 | Calculus AB BC | Math        | 2000-01-02 | Pearson Education |  325 |
| 1111111111111 |    2 | Calculus AB BC | Math        | 2000-01-02 | Pearson Education |  325 |
| 1112223334445 |    2 | Test           | tst         | 2019-05-05 | testaa            |  123 |
| 1212365454789 |    1 | Math           | Mathematics | 2000-02-02 | Pearson Education |  450 |
| 1234567980605 |    2 | Chaos Theory   | Mathematics | 1990-09-10 | Steven Stugart    |  450 |
+---------------+------+----------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+------+
```

Author Table

```
+---------------+------+--------+----+---------+
|     isbn      | copy |   AF   | AM |   AL    |
+---------------+------+--------+----+---------+
| 1111111111111 |    1 | John   | M  | Smith   |
| 1111111111111 |    2 | John   | M  | Smith   |
| 1231231231231 |    1 | Peyton | M  | Manning |
| 1234567980605 |    2 | Tony   | W  | Stark   |
+---------------+------+--------+----+---------+
```

Comment: do you have id or create date to help you get the last inserted value in book table

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean?

Comment: you need to get the last inserted row in the book table to get the value of the isbn and insert it in author table

Comment: And how would I go about doing that? :O I've never really done anything like thatt

Comment: This is a weird data structure...why is the Author associated with a specific ISBN and copy number? Surely, since an author can have many books published, and a book can have many authors, you would have an Authors table containing an ID field, and the name fields). Then you have a BookAuthors table, containing 3 fields: ISBN, copy number, and Author ID - ISBN+copy would be a foreign key to the Book table, and AuthorID to the Authors table. The primary key would be a compound key of all 3 fields.

Comment: ....That's how you represent a many-to-many relationship. I don't understand what your current structure is supposed to represent, or how you would end up entering author details _after_ the book details - the author must exist before the book, surely? Maybe I missed something but to me your tables don't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify the structure of your table to make it easier to perform your queries in the future, for example, adding primary key would help you to keep track of your records

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`book` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `isbn` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `copy` INT NULL,
  `gener` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `pdate` DATETIME NULL,
  `publisher` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `size` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `test`.`author` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `book_id` INT NULL,
  `af` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `am` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `al` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `author_book_id_idx` (`book_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `author_book_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`book` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


INSERT INTO `book` (`id`, `isbn`, `copy`, `gener`, `title`, `pdate`, `publisher`, `size`) VALUES (NULL, 'test2', '2', 'math', 'test2', '2019-05-06 00:00:00', 'test', '2');

insert into author (`book_id`,`af`,`am`,`al`) select max(id),'test af','test am','test al' from book;
```

a better structure is to link each book to its author not the opposite since each author may have more than one book

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`book` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `isbn` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `copy` INT NULL,
  `gener` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `pdate` DATETIME NULL,
  `publisher` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `size` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`author_id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)),
CONSTRAINT `author_book_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`author` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

edit: 
if you dont want to re-create the tables you can just alter the book table

```
ALTER TABLE `test`.`book` 
ADD COLUMN `created_at` DATETIME NULL AFTER `size`;
```

and then the insert should look like

```
insert into author (`isbn`, `copy`,`af`,`am`,`al`) select isbn, copy,'test af','test am','test al' from book where created_at=(select max(created_at) from book );
```

Comment: I see so you basically just did two insert statements which are linked by the book_id?

Comment: yes, using PK and FK and INDEX will also help you in your queries when you want to get data, if you think this helps you please upvote the answer

Comment: Sadly it doesn't because creating a new table would do way more harm than good so there isn't a way currently to get the first two values from the book columns and have them update into the author table?

Comment: you need to add timestamp (or created datetime) column at least to help get the last inserted value